# How to remove duplicates from mysql results while applying sort

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `a_athletes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `a_events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `athlete_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `a_events` (`id`, `name`, `athlete_id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'Long jump', 1, '2023-02-18'),
(2, 'Row', 1, '2023-02-09'),
(3, 'Sprint', 2, '2023-02-10'),
(4, 'Sprint', 1, '2023-02-14'),
(5, 'Long Jump', 2, '2023-02-20');

INSERT INTO `a_athletes` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Sarah'),
(2, 'Simon'),
(3, 'Barbera');
```

I want to get all the results where the athlete has no 'Row' events associated.

I have the following query which achieves this:

```
select * 
from a_athletes
left join a_events on a_athletes.id = a_events.athlete_id
where a_athletes.id not in (
    select a_athletes.id
    from a_athletes
    inner join a_events on a_athletes.id = a_events.athlete_id
    where a_events.`name` = 'Row'
)
 order by a_events.`date`;
```

Which gives these results:

```
3,Barbera,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
2,Simon,3,Sprint,2,2023-02-10
2,Simon,5,Long Jump,2,2023-02-20
```

I want to display these results in a UI table of athletes without duplicates. I want to ignore any results after the `a_athletes.id` has already appeared in the results. The results need to be paginated, so this would have to be done within the sql query.

In this example the expected output would be:

```
3,Barbera,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
2,Simon,3,Sprint,2,2023-02-10
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Quick nit-pick. a_events.athlete_id should probably be the same type as a_athletes.id if you intend to use it as an undeclared foreign key. If you want no duplicates, then you need to define what should be returned if there are duplicates. Do you want the earliest or latest date, or highest id? I think your SQL would be better if you removed athletes from the NOT IN query. Also, this isn't a free coding service. To paginate results will require more than just a few line of SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM   a_athletes a1
       LEFT JOIN a_events e1
              ON a1.id = e1.athlete_id
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   a_events e2
                   WHERE  a1.id = e2.athlete_id 
                      AND e2.`name` = 'Row')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   a_events e3
                   WHERE  a1.id = e3.athlete_id 
                      AND e1.id > e3.id)   
ORDER  BY e1.`date`;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tdbovS19)